# Deleting a referenced scope object from inside an isolated scope - angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-binding

I have an angular directive uses the `=` operator to two-way bind an isolated scope with an attribute of its parent scope:

```
app.directive('nestedDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        link: function($scope){
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

I understand that any changes to $scope.model will propagate to the parent scope. However, deleting $scope.model does not propagate. `delete($scope.model)` My question thus: How do I delete the referenced variable and propagate the removal to the parent scope.

[This codepen](http://cdpn.io/rneKa) should illustrate what I'm trying to do not (Not even watching the scope fires an event)

Comment: " However, deleting $scope.model does not propagate ".
How do you delete '$scope.model' ?

Comment: delete($scope.model), I'd love to know a nicer way of doing that. You can see it in the codepen: http://codepen.io/goodafternoon/pen/rneKa

Comment: Maybe you are deleting "$scope.model" structure, but not value pointed by this structure.
Try $scope.model = null

Comment: Scope.model = null works, but what I really need to do is delete the variable not set it to null

Answer (score 2):

This question gets asked very, very often, so I'll start by referring to the [wiki article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Basically, follow the "dot rule" : if you need to modify a property (directly), scope it under another property so that JS prototypal inheritance can kick in :

```
var model = {prop: "val"};
var a = {model: model};

model = null;
console.log(a.model.prop); // prints val

var b = {a: a};
a.model = null;

console.log(b.a.model); // prints null
```

This is the same here (even if this doesn't use a prototypal inheritance to keep things simple).

Comment: it's not quite the same, if you look at the codepen that I referred to: http://codepen.io/goodafternoon/pen/rneKa you can see that the item I'm trying to delete is part of an array in the parents scope, also the whole point of creating isolate scopes in angular is to isolate them, going up the prototype chain defeats that purpose.

Comment: You can't unset something you don't have control upon. Just namespace model and isolate that.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code pen source below, i'm sure there's a simpler way of doing this but i've just tried this and it works, it should start you on the right path:

```
<ul ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <dir model="data.children" child="child" ng-repeat="child in data.children"></dir>
</ul>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.children = [
    {name: 'Ben'},
    {name: 'Heffler'},
    {name: 'Schubert'} 
  ];

  $scope.$watchCollection('data.children', function(){
    console.log("children shallow watch", $scope);
  });
  $scope.$watch('data.children', function(){
    console.log("children deep watch",$scope);
  }, true);
});

app.directive('dir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '=',
      child:'='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>{{child.name}} <button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.remove = function(){
        // I'm just deleting the first one as an example.
        delete(scope.model[0]);
        console.log("children inner scope", scope)
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I'm not sure why you would want to delete the properties but i'm sure you have your reasons, just to show you it is possible.

EDIT

Here is the edited code pen (see the console logs to see the deleted items in scope). http://cdpn.io/Ghmvk